# Are there more tickering settings I can tune?

Tags: javafx, codenameone, ticker

Are there any easy ways to do the following when tickering on a Label?

1. Pause for 3 sec every time the text gets back to its original position?
2. Ease in and ease out the intervals between ticks.  Similar to the JavaFX Motion for easing in and out?
3. Make the ticking flow more smoothly instead of being a little jumpy?

Comment: I would suggest for future cases that you split such questions into 3 questions since if a developer doesn't know the answer to one of these he might not post an answer on the question to which he does know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you will need to do it manually.

Just override `Label` and override its `animate()` method. I haven't tried this but something like this can work for all of your requirements:

```
Label tickeredLabel = new Label(myText) {
    Motion tickeringMotion;
    long pauseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    public boolean animate() {
       long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

       // wait 3 seconds for tickering
       if(currentTime - pauseTime < 3000) {
          return false;
       }

       // use ease in/out motion over 5 seconds
       if(tickeringMotion == null) {
          tickeringMotion = Motion.createEaseInOutMotion(0, getStringWidth(getStyle().getFont(), 5000);
          tickeringMotion.start();
       } else {
          // when motion is finished return to 3 second delay
          if(tickeringMotion.isFinished()) {
             tickeringMotion = null;
             pauseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
          }
       }
       setShiftText(tickeringMotion.getValue());
       return changed;
    }
};
```

To smooth out tickering further just make it move one pixel at a time specifically